# Chtml::link not getting ID of event attendee

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently trying to redirect a user from a view in the events folder, going to the user folder with the id of the event attendee.

The issue I'm having is that the url is returning without the idea, in this case it should be 56. /user/InviteGuest/eventId but no ID

```
<p>You can also invite a guest to attend this event with you. 
<?php echo CHtml::link("Click here to invite a guest", array('/user/InviteGuest', 'eventId' => EventAttendees::model()->id))?></p>
```

It doesn't seem to be getting the ID from the model and populating the field ID, it works fine when I link from within the event attendee views.

edit. for example in a view in the eventattendees folder

```
array('label' => 'Invite Guests','buttonType'=>'link',  'icon' => 'group', 'url' => array('/user/InviteGuest', 'eventId' => $data->id)),
```

work fine

Comment: show the controller action that call/render the view  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
'eventId' => EventAttendees::model()->id
```

This is not getting any data, unless your EventAttendees' id is set to 56 by default, which is really odd. "id" is usually used for primary keys.

I think what you're missing is to load your data. Maybe something like this:

```
// Exemple, not actual tested code
// In your controller
$attendee = EventAttendees::model()->findByAttributes( array( 
    'whatever'=>$something,
));

$this->render('view', array(
    'attendee'=>$attendee,
));



// In your view
<?php echo CHtml::link("Click here to invite a guest", array('/user/InviteGuest', 'eventId' => $attendee->id))?></p>
```

Comment: If I use just find id it gets the first result of the table, so it is looking at the ID and the table but not returning the relationship in this case. I can give it another go with the above but from my first look it seems as if the ID is also being passed through into the render via the loadmodel action

Edit. Tried loading it through again, with the specific details. No luck, it just can't find the relation.

Comment: It seems the other answer that was here has been deleted. but using 

'eventId' => EventAttendees::model()->find($id)->id)) , finds the first instance of the id, so it is finding the data, just not the correct relation

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're talking about with "returning the relationship". You're not getting data because you're just not loading it. If you don't get the correct data, it's because you're not loading the correct one, so check your search parameters.